# Returning a SYS_REFCURSOR from an Oracle Function/Stored Proc To VBA

Tags: oracle, vba, excel, oracle11g, adodb

I am attempting to retrieve a *recordset* back into the *ADODB* object using *VBA*.  I have a very basic function inside an Oracle(11g) database package:

```
            CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE "DATABASE"."PKG_INDEX" AS
            FUNCTION get_diary(event_date IN DATE := NULL) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR;
            END PKG_AIT_INDEX;

            CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY "DATABASE"."PKG_INDEX" AS
            FUNCTION get_diary(event_date IN DATE := NULL)
            RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
            IS
            my_cursor  SYS_REFCURSOR;
            search_date EVENTS.EVENT_DATE%TYPE;
            BEGIN
            If event_date Is Null Then
            search_date := TRUNC(SYSDATE);
            Else
            search_date := event_date;
            END IF;
            OPEN my_cursor FOR
            SELECT *
            FROM Table
            WHERE EVENT_DATE > search_date;
            RETURN my_cursor;
            END get_diary;
            END PKG_INDEX;
```

The function behaves as expected when called within DB Visualiser:

```
            --/
            DECLARE
            rc SYS_REFCURSOR;
            BEGIN
            rc := PKG_INDEX.GET_DIARY(NULL);
            END;
            /
```

I want to call the Function from VBA and get the recordset.  I have tried numerous different ways and am unable to come up with a solution.

```
            Public Function ExecuteFunction(sDBName As String, sDBEnv As String, sDBRegion As String, sCommand As String, Optional sDBConn As String, Optional sError As String) As Recordset
            Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
            Dim oCmd As ADODB.Command
            Dim oParam As ADODB.Parameter
            Dim oRst As ADODB.Recordset

            Const SOURCE As String = "ExecuteQuery"

            If GetDBConnection(oConn, sDBName, sDBEnv, sDBRegion, sDBConn, sError) Then

            Set oCmd = New ADODB.Command
            With oCmd
            Set .ActiveConnection = oConn
            .CommandType = adCmdText
            .CommandText = "BEGIN :returnValue :=PKG_INDEX.GET_DIARY; END;"

            Set oParam = .CreateParameter("returnValue", adVariant, adParamInputOutput, 100000)
            .Parameters.Append oParam

            Set oRst = .Execute
            End With
            Set ExecuteFunction = oRst

            End If

            End Function
```

The above was one attempt but nothing is passed back into the parameter and I get the:

```
ORA-01008: not all variables bound
```

My connection String is:

```
Provider=MSDAORA;User ID=XXX;Password=XXX;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST 
= (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = XXXX)(PORT = XXXX)) ) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = XXXX)));
```

Seems to be quite difficult to achieve something very easy.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Finally found a good example:

[Calling Stored Procedures From ADO](http://www.brynthomas.com/examples/ADODemo.html)

Or using CreatePLSQLDynaset Method:

[CreatePLSQLDynaset Method](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/win.101/b10118/o4o00325.htm)

Comment: Try this?  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322160

Comment: Found that slightly misleading because VBA does not have the return type on the param that .net class has.  Example above seems to work (finally).  Thank you anyway.

Comment: Although don't really understand .CommandText arg person in the 'Calling Stored Procedure From ADO' link is using.  .CommandText = {CALL PackageName.ProcName(?,?,?, {resultset 0, o_resultset},0)}....  o_resultset is an input parameter but where is resultset defined?  Is this the best way of doing it?  As usual, any comments much appreciated.

Comment: The "Calling Stored Procedures From ADO" link worked for me. Thank you so much for shareing; I was going crazy trying to get this to work!